# Deleting specific character in line

Tags: vim, vi

I want to delete specific char in line, with Vim, for example:

```
for a, b in enumerate(def}):
```

If the cursor it is on the beginning, I want to know if is possible to remove the typo `{` without moving to the that position.
I already tried `f`, `t`, `|` keys, but as motions keys, they ended up deleting the entire line.

Is there a "pointwise-like" key-movement that will remove that specific char? Or it is not worthy at all?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simplest version is to move the cursor and then delete (since it’s a single character):

```
f}x
```

This is different from `df}`—the first reads « find a } and then delete it », while the second reads « delete everything from my current position to where you find a }, inclusive » (`t`—‘til—would be the exclusive).

As it turns out, `x` is a synonym for `dl`, which is « delete a character covered by moving one to the right ». (Yes, I know, hjkl. Trust me, it’s more intuitive if you *don’t* think about it.)

If you want to go back to the beginning of the line, you can hit `0` after that, or possibly ``` `` ```.

In a typo that simple, you could also do

```
:substitute/}/
```

Or `:s/}/` for short, but that’s a lot of typing.

Overall, there is no reason not to move the cursor.

Comment: Just want to add that you can hit `0` or `^` afterwards to take you back to the start of the line, so the full command would be `f}x0`

Comment: @StunBrick see my 4th paragraph.

Comment: sorry, I missed that entirely.